# Changing Footer on last Page of Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro-Enabled Excel Template that will change the footer on the last page of the Excel File, but since Excel itself does not allow the last page to change I am trying to use VBA code to correct this issue.

I have included my VBA code below, and IO originally had it in "ThisWorkbook", and it worked out well. However, after I used the Template to export and create a Macro-Enabled Workbook, it will only sometimes work now. Sometimes I get following error:

> Run-time error '1004': The number must be between 1 and 2147483647.
>   Try again by entering a number in this range.

The error occurs in the commented area in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim LastPage
Dim Rght As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Rght = ActiveSheet.Range("C1")
LastPage = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")

Cancel = True

MsgBox LastPage & " pages will be printed"

LastPage:
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=LastPage - 1
        .RightFooter = "Peer Check: _________________________" & "&""InspectionXpert GDT,&10" & Rght
        ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=LastPage, To:=LastPage
        .RightFooter = "" & Rght
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With
End Sub
```

Edit: I was able to determine that my issue lies within the line below.

```
LastPage = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
```

It seems that for some reason, it believes there is only 1 page that is available to print when there are 6 pages.